# Updating Parameters Within setInterval() - Parameters do not update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, setinterval

This will be my last question, should I receive an answer. I have a nodeJS program, which runs damn near perfectly. However, I appear to be stuck in a loop at the end. The reason for this I believe is because I base when to kill my loop, off of a Database Item, fed into the function through `setInterval()`.

This Parameter, say set at 0, and raised to 1 at the end of the script, always starts at 0 again when the setInterval function is called. It gets updated in the database, and in the script at the end of the function, ut when the function restarts, it has the original value. Any ideas to fix this?

#### My code

```
router.get('/run', function(req, res) {
  console.log("res.locals.user.username);


  const receiver = res.locals.user.email;
  // let threshold = parseInt(res.locals.user.threshold);
  const check_rate = parseInt(res.locals.user.checkRate);
  const email = res.locals.user.Login;
  const password = res.locals.user.Password;
  const props = {
    var1,
    var2
  };

  const switches = "";


  adduser.find({
    ownerUsername: res.locals.user.username
  }).then(function(results) {
    res.render('index', {
      var12: results
    });

    setInterval(function() {
      let threshold = parseInt(res.locals.user.threshold);

      doSomething(threshld, check_rt, email, password, var1,);
    }, 10 * 1000);
    // console.log("restarting function \n Threshold value is " +res.locals.user.threshold);
  })

});


function doSomething(Threshold, checkRate, email, password, var1, receiver, switches) {
  console.log("Running dosomething() Now");



      if (res.total_missed >= Threshold) {
        console.log(res.total_missed);
        console.log("res.total_missed is = " + res.total_missed);


        Threshld++
        User.update({
          var1: var1
        }, {
          thrshld: Threshld,

        }, function(err, res) {
          //handle it
        })
        doSomethingElse(password, email, props);




      }
    }
  })
}
```

Okay so yes this is the best example of my code that I can make without just copy pasting.  The issue here is that the line `let Threshold = res.locals.user.threshold;` is not being updated, and pulls a 0 from the database every time, when the threshold in the database gets incremented and updated to 1 during the `doSomething()` function.

Once again, thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: That `setInterval` inside route handler looks bad. There will be new intervals each time the route is accessed. Are you trying to throttle user actions? Whatever you're trying to do, it seems to be XY problem that should be addressed in another way. Consider explaining your real case instead of supposed solution.

Comment: This is my real case, just not my real code. I need an integer variable to be updated through setInterval, is this a possibility?

Comment: `doSomething` name doesn't look like real case, it's more of an abstraction. It's unclear what this variable is for and how the app should work. This decreases your chances to get a helpful answer on SO. Again, setInterval shouldn't be inside route handler. You will create a ton of intervals and freeze the server.

Comment: I got it working guys but ty :)

Answer (score 0):

`let Threshold = res.locals.user.threshold;` is not pulling from the database.  You're pulling it off the response object...

So you should ask yourself, why is a `0` being sent over the wire to your GET endpoint?  And also why is it on the response?

Furthermore, are you sure you're updating the user in the DB?  This is what I see:

```
function doSomething(Threshold, checkRate, email, password, var1, receiver, switches) {
  console.log("Running dosomething() Now");
  console.log("Threshold in Start of Check Function is = " + Threshold);



      if (res.total_missed >= Threshold) {
        console.log(res.total_missed);
        console.log("res.total_missed is = " + res.total_missed);


        Threshold++
        User.update({
          username: var1      // <--- searches for username given some param: var1
        }, {
          threshold: Threshold,  /// < ---- updates this user property with this new value

        }, function(err, numberAffected, rawResponse) {
          //handle it
        })
```

So you feed the user over `var1`.  Let's look at how you're injecting that user:

`doSomething(threshold, check_rate, email, password, var1, receiver, switches);`

So you directly pass in `var1`.  No idea what var1 represents to begin with.  Bad naming conventions.  That aside... where is it set?  The only other thing I see, based on code you've provided, is:

`const props = {
    var1,
    var2
  };`

So, my guess is that you're providing `null` or `undefined` to your database update function, and it's not actually updating the user.  Then I will further bet, that somewhere along the way, when you query and provide data to your request on the `locals.user`, it's just always finding 0 because your'e not updating it.

Furthermore, you are also pulling a ton of information off your `response` object, and not your `request`...

Comment: I am 100% certain I am updating the database with the incremented value. I will read over your answer now.

Comment: Aall of the variables are set on another page. Setting the variable really shouldn't affect it so long as it is set.

Comment: Thanks for the effort so far guys. I guess I will just post my full project next time. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: You could post a link to Git repo or even better a small working prototype on Replit: https://repl.it/repls

Answer (score 0):

very simply,

initialize your variable at the beginning of this page, outside of the get request.